# using regular expression in javascript to return some part of words that start with a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string containing several strings delimited by spaces, I'm trying to find the one that starts with "dtl-" and then return only the part of the matched word that comes after "dtl-" (in this case they are digits)

For example, if the string is:

```
class = "odd dtl-78634 blue active";
```

then I need to return:

```
"78634"
```

When I use the following code:

```
var id = class.match(/dtl-(\d+)/);
```

id will be an array containing two values: "dtl-78634" and "78634"

I can use id[1] which will hold my desired value, but my questions are:

1) Why am I receiving two different matches? One including what I call the "signature" (in this case "dtl-"), and the other one does not include the signature.

2) Is there a way in regular expression to specifically generate one of the two types of returned matches?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding 2), you can use positive lookbehind to match only the characters following a certain pattern: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thank you, I will check the link.

Answer (score 1):

id[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, id[1] will have the text that matched the first captured string.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is already embedded in the question. - My question is why there are two results generated and if there is a way in reg expression to control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be that difficult. And i don't think you need  regex to do this. Simple split will do the job for you.

Consider a simple logic. First split the variable using `-` and then split using `empty space` like this :

```
var idT = "odd dtl-78634 blue active";
var arrayIDT = idT.split("-");
console.log(arrayIDT[1]);
var id = arrayIDT[1].split(" ");
console.log(id[0]);
```

Find the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/FXhLx/

Comment: Thanks, but the point of the question is to come up with a general solution in order to find a string which starts with a specific sequence of characters, within a larger string contents of which is not known at run-time. Your solution is specific to the given sample.